# ayuda con validacion en js de un array

Tags: javascript

quiero hacer una validacion en js de un array para evitar que se repitan los datos que envió, pero me esta dando un error y quiero que me orienten para ver que estoy haciendo mal el error es el siguiente, `Uncaught TypeError: element.trim is not a function` esta son los datos que guardo en el array

```
 (2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {imei1: "a", imeip: "1"}
1: {imei1: "bnd", imeip: "1"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

y esta es la funcion que estoy haciendo

```
function existeImei(imei1, idx){

  var imeiexiste = detalles[idx].detallesImei.find(element => element.trim().toLowerCase() === imei1.trim().toLowerCase());

  if(imeiexiste){
      return true;
  }else{
      return false;
  }


}
```

pero me esta dando el `Uncaught TypeError: element.trim is not a function`

Comment: Porsupuesto que te va a dar ese error, a menos de que estes comparando el array de objects correcto, porque hasta donde se no veo ninguna propiedad llamada detallesImei en tu arreglo de objetos, puede ser ese el problema??

Comment: Si `detallesImei` es el *array* que pusiste arriba, cada uno de estos elementos es un objeto, por lo que deberás comparar el campo `imei1` de cada uno: *e.g.:* `element.imei1.trim().toLowerCase() === imei.trim().toLowerCase()`

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Antes que nada, tu código falla antes de generar el error que vos especificás. ¿Estás seguro de que no estás omitiendo ningún código relevante?

Comment: gracias ya puede aclarar mi duda gracias a ustedes

Answer (score 0):

Obviando los errores de tu pregunta, aquí hay un código que realiza lo que querés:

```js
var imeis = [
  {
    "imei1": "a",
    "imeip": "1"
  },
  {
    "imei1": "bnd",
    "imeip": "1"
  }
];

function existe(imei)
{
 var tmp_imeis = Array();
 var imei_existe = false;
 imeis.forEach(function (tmp_imei) {
  tmp_imeis.push(tmp_imei.imei1.toLowerCase());
 });

 if (tmp_imeis.indexOf(imei.toLowerCase()) != -1)
 {
  imei_existe = true;
 }
 return imei_existe;
}

console.log("¿Existe 'a'? " + existe("a"));
console.log("¿Existe 'bnd'? " + existe("bnd"));
console.log("¿Existe 'fx'? " + existe("fx"));
```

Básicamente la función `existe` itera sobre la variable `imeis` y añade cada `.imei1` a `tmp_imeis`, después verifica si `imei` existe en `tmp_imeis` y devuelve `true` o `false` dependiendo de eso.